# CountTokenizing a field, turning into columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm working with data that look something like this:

```
ID      PATH         GROUP  
11937   MM-YT-UJ-OO  GT  
11938   YT-RY-LM     TQ  
11939   XX-XX-OT     DX
```

I'd like to tokenize the PATH column into n-grams and then one-hot encode those into their own columns so I'd end up with something like:

```
ID     GROUP   MM  YT  UJ  OO  RY  LM  XX  OT  MM-YT  YT-UH ...  
11937  GT      1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1      1
```

I could also use counted tokens rather than one-hot, so 11939 would have a 2 in the XX column instead of a 1, but I can work with either.

I can tokenize the column quite easily with scikitlearn CountVectorizer, but then I have to cbind the `ID` and `GROUP` fields.  Is there a standard way to do this or a best practice that anyone has discovered?

Answer (score 1):

A solution:

```
df.set_index(['ID', 'GROUP'], inplace=True)
pd.get_dummies(df.PATH.str.split('-', expand=True).stack())\
              .groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().reset_index()
```

---

Isolate the ID and GROUP columns as index. Then convert the string to cell items

```
df.PATH.str.split('-', expand=True)
Out[37]: 
              0   1   2     3
ID    GROUP                  
11937 GT     MM  YT  UJ    OO
11938 TQ     YT  RY  LM  None
11939 DX     XX  XX  OT  None
```

Get them into a single column of data

```
df.PATH.str.split('-', expand=True).stack()
Out[38]: 
ID     GROUP   
11937  GT     0    MM
              1    YT
              2    UJ
              3    OO
11938  TQ     0    YT
              1    RY
              2    LM
11939  DX     0    XX
              1    XX
              2    OT
```

`get_dummies` bring the counter as columns spread accross rows

```
pd.get_dummies(df.PATH.str.split('-', expand=True).stack())
Out[39]: 
               LM  MM  OO  OT  RY  UJ  XX  YT
ID    GROUP                                  
11937 GT    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
            1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
            2   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
            3   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
11938 TQ    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
            1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
            2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11939 DX    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
            1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
            2   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

Group by the data per ID, GROUP (levels 0 and 1 in the index) to sum up the rows together and have one line per tuple. And finally reset the index to get ID and GROUP column back as regular columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like that.

```
# Test data
df = DataFrame({'GROUP': ['GT', 'TQ', 'DX'],
 'ID': [11937, 11938, 11939],
 'PATH': ['MM-YT-UJ-OO', 'YT-RY-LM', 'XX-XX-OT']})

# Expanding data and creating on column by token
tmp = pd.concat([df.loc[:,['GROUP', 'ID']], 
                 df['PATH'].str.split('-', expand=True)], axis=1)
# Converting wide to long format
tmp = pd.melt(tmp, id_vars=['ID', 'GROUP'])
# Now grouping and counting
tmp.groupby(['ID', 'GROUP', 'value']).count().unstack().fillna(0)

#             variable                                   
# value             LM   MM   OO   OT   RY   UJ   XX   YT
# ID    GROUP                                            
# 11937 GT         0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
# 11938 TQ         1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
# 11939 DX         0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0
```